# php array mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query like this with an IN clause

sql = "

SOME QUERY
WHERE some_item IN ()

";

Do I have to do a for loop to to put all items of the php array into the IN clause or is there a function or method that does this?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implode

```
$item_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // somehow populate this array
$item_list = implode(',', $item_ids);

$sql = "SOME QUERY WHERE some_item IN ({$item_list})";
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

here is a quick example :
    $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

Answer (score 1):

For numeric values in an array:

```
sprintf("... WHERE some_item IN (%s) ...",implode(",",$numeric_array));
```

For string values:

```
sprintf("... WHERE some_item IN ('%s') ...",implode("','",$escaped_string_array));
```

Be careful to escape the values when building the arrays.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you could do an array_filter() before with a call to escape method etc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of things in an array, you can use JOIN to build it for you.  It's easiest for numeric values, since you don't have to put quotes around things.  Something like this:

```
$sql = 'SOME QUERY WHERE some_item IN (' . join(',', $a_myData) . ')';
```

If your array contains strings, you should escape that data as you put the data into the array.  But once you've done that, you can do something similar to above, adding quote marks.

```
$sql = 'SOME QUERY WHERE some_item IN ("' . join('","', $a_myData) . '")';
```

One potential issue is an empty array, since the above example would give you `IN ("")`, which could potentially match something you don't want.

The above example also doesn't account for NULL values.  One way around that is to populate your array with the strings with quotes already around them (so you can have `NULL` as its own value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/implode), like:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN(' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```